# use Auth for checking permission in spatie lara permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm use Laravel 9. when I'm use permission checking by `Auth` Like:

```
Auth::user()->can('permission_name');
```

or

```
auth()->user()->hasPermissionTo('permission_name')
```

the program return error: `Undefined method 'can'.intelephense(1013)`.

now I'm use:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$user->can('permission_name');
```

if there is better way a lot thanks if you tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the better way to implement permission is using
[Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware)

but you can use just like this, on every function with Request parameter

```
$request->user()->can('my-permission')
```

So if you using middleware,
On the **handle** function in middleware you can pass a parameter that contain the permission

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission = null)
{
    if ($permission !== null && !$request->user()->can($permission)) {
        abort(404);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and on the route you can pass the parameter to the middleware like this

```
Route::put('/post/{id}', 'TheControllerPath')->middleware('your_registered_middleware_name:my-permission');
```

Comment: good answer, but if I'm not using `$request`?

Comment: I discovered this code `Auth::user()->can('permission_name');` is running but show me Error. thank you for anwering.

Comment: "is running but show me Error", maybe the error just on the IDE/text editor, not from laravel, sometimes the plugin on the text editor cannot discover some of laravel component so it's causing text edit show error